# How do I call a function inside another controller file in PHP?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have one function I need to call from another file with Codeigniter and I'm not sure how to do this.

The one file is in controllers/Jobassignment.php, which contains a function called createassignments() that I need to call from controllers/Reporting.php. I am pretty new at Codeigniter, so how would I call the createassignments function from Reporting.php?

I tried

```
$this->load->library('controllers/jobassignment');
$this->jobassignment->createassignments();
```

But this isn't working.

It has been called in a form tag:

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url( 'jobassignment/createassignments' ); ?>
```

but I can't do that in the middle of a function.

They are both controller files. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If you need to call a controller method from another controller, then you should probably abstract that code out to a helper or library and call it from both controllers.

Comment: Is the `$this->load->library('controllers/jobassignment');` working? I mean `$this->jobassignment` is an instance of `jobassignment`?

Comment: @claudio, I get the following error: "Unable to load the requested class: Jobassignment"

Comment: @RivaPortman what's the name of the class inside jobassignment controller file?

Comment: `class Jobassignment extends MY_Controller {`

Comment: What does "isn't working" mean? There isn't any reason you cannot call a different controller as a `<form action=...`

Comment: if you want two controllers can access the same function then you need to put that function in helper which is the best option, if you want us to do then please share that function here or read CI documentation for helper function, you will definitely do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has nothing to do with Codeigniter. If the Jobassignment.php is a PHP class you can make an instance of it and then call that function:

```
user namespace/Jobassignment

$jobassignment = new Jobassignment();

$jobassignment->createassignments();
```

but if this method you create is going to call in other classes you must make a class under Helpers directory and then call the method the way that I explained.

Don't make instance of request class. you must make a helper class to handel this.

Comment: Thank you, I will try that.

Comment: I don't know how to do that. I will look it up. Thank you for the help.

Comment: @RivaPortman make a directory name it Helpers. add a PHP class in it with the name of  Jobassignment.php and put that createassignments() method (function) in that class. after that all you have to do is make an instance of class and call that method everywhere you want

Comment: @RivaPortman If the answer is what you need don't forget to make it as best answer and give an upvote. thanks

Comment: The answer is not a good solution when using CodeIgniter (CI). First, CodeIgniter < v4 does not use namespace. Second, and more important, is that CI cannot successfully instantiate two controllers at the same time. Technically it can, but it will likely produce a lot of errors.

Comment: @DFriend Maybe you are right my friend. then it must require the file in the old fashion way

Comment: Or, as you suggest, in a helper. A custom class in /application/libraries might be a good solution too. That could be successfully loaded and used by any number of controllers.

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to make the action of the form a method in a different controller then your code

```
<form action="<?php echo base_url( 'jobassignment/createassignments' ); ?>
```

is perfectly fine. You just have to understand that you are doing a redirect and code execution in the current controller is done. Understand that a `<form action...>` is always a redirect where the input element values of the form are sent to the server.

Because it is a redirect there is no reason to call `$this->load->library('controllers/jobassignment');`